# How to Rotate a TextField at Libgdx Android App?

Tags: android, user-interface, libgdx, textfield

Hi im developing a game with libgdx for android. My problem is that code:

```
    button = new TextButton("SEND", skin);
    button.setPosition(300,200);
    button.setSize(200, 40);
    button.setTransform(true);
    button.setRotation(90);

    user = new TextField("", skin);
    user.setPosition(300,250);
    user.setSize(200, 40);
    user.setRotation(90);
```

user isnt rotating with setRotation. I would like to rotate this textfield. thanks for every suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `setTransform(true)` on Actors to enable rotation. If `Textfield` doesn't have that method, wrap it in a `Group`.